# Project Arduino ZigBEE Based Wireless Sensor Network

Tags: c

Hey I am working on Masters Project. My Project title is Arduino ZigBEE Based Wireless Sensor Network. I have to interface DHT22 Sensor with Arduino and send it to xbee and Transmit wirelessly using other Xbee to PC.I have interfaced Sensor but I am stucked with the Xbee Configurations and Arduino code to transmit and receive data on the other side on PC. Can anybody help me in this issue ??

Comment: There is no way to answer this question, you are being *way* too vague.

Comment: The question is I have to send the sensor(DHT22 Temperature and Humidity Sensor ) data to Xbee and transmit it to the PC. How can I configure my XBees in Router and Coordinator mode so that I get the required output??

Comment: Read the manual/app notes for them. If you have a problem where doing what it says doesn't work, post what you've tried and we can go from there.

Comment: I have interfaced DHT22 Sensor with Arduino and able to visualize Temperature and Humidity readings on Arduino Serial Monitor.     I have configured transmitter Xbee as a router in API mode with following settings.

Comment: ID - PAN ID – 3332
DH – Destination Address High – Address of my receiving Xbee 
DL – Destination Address Low – Address of my receiving Xbee 
AP – API Enable – 2
EE – Encryption Enable – 1 (for implementing secured network)
KY – Encryption key – 4

Comment: We are not a consulting or coding site. Talk to your tutor for directions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of arduino, the X-Bee itself can be used as an MCU. Use the GPIOs of the X-Bee for this purpose. [This](http://lookmanowire.blogspot.in/search/label/Sensor%20Network?m=1) might help for your project. This digital IO passing can be learnt from here. Learn how to configure the X-Bee. It can be used in a lot different ways than expected. Open the X-CTU and check the parameters. It'll help a lot.